# how do i edit HTML inside string JAVA CODE easily

Tags: java, android, html

i developed android app and i used HTML code to Print the result in formatted form.
the code will be like this :

```
String adress = editText1.getText().toString();
String phone = editText2.getText().toString();
String licenseNo = editText3.getText().toString();
```

```
 "\n" +
                    "        <div class=\"down\">\n" +
                    "            <div class=\"EASY\">\n" +
                    "                <img src=\"" + image + "\" alt=\"QR\" >\n" +

                    "            </div>\n" +
                    "            <table class=\" info_table\">\n" +
                    "                <tbody>\n" +
                    "                    <tr>\n" +
                    "                        <td class=\"info\">" + phone + "</td>\n" +
                    "                        <td class=\"info\"> " + licenseNo + "</td>\n" +
                    "                    </tr>\n" +
                    "                    <tr>\n" +
                    "                        <td class=\"info_A\" colspan=\"2\"> " + adress + "</td>\n" +
                    "                    </tr>\n" +
                    "                </tbody>\n" +
                    "            </table>\n" +
                    "        </div>";
```

as you see it should contain `\n` and `+` because its inside a string object contained variable values from user input.
i faced some difficulty when i need to Edit this Piece of code cose i will test it inside the application.
my question is what is the best way to get this code to edit and preview it outside android studio and reinsert it again.
i used find and replace but it make some problems.

hope i explained enough

Comment: Create a file and paste the HTML contents, then view the results in your browser. Modify your HTML file accordingly. Then save the file in the `res` or `resources` folder in your project. In your app, read the contents of this file instead of hardcode the HTML output.

Comment: OK how to inject the variables from user input

Answer (score 0):

You can create a XML file in the resources folder, [read it](https://mkyong.com/java/java-read-a-file-from-resources-folder/) and then use [format](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-format) in order to change the values there.